# C# WebClient returning corrupt non-English text

Tags: c#, regex, listbox, non-ascii-characters

So first of all, I have a program that gets the source file of a Web site in a String. Then, with a regex, it reads a specific name and stores it in a string, then displays it in a listbox.

Here comes my problem. If the name contains Russian letters, or any other non-English characters, it won't display it correctly (instead of displaying the Russian characters, it displays stuff like this: `Đ•Đ¶ĐµĐ´Đ˝`.

I need to recognize Russian characters or any other non-English characters.

**EDIT:**

Fixed the issued by simply specifying the encoding in the `WebClient`:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: And what regex are you using, and against what input string?

Comment: MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(html2, @"The Expression");foreach (Match m1 in m)
                    { And here comes the second code

Comment: Updated the post,hope it's more clear now

Comment: It is not clear what your `html` or `html2` look like. Does the text look corrupt inside? Then, why using a regex? Depending on what value and where you are looking for it, you might be safer using an HTML parser.

Comment: Ok so,I have tested,and both ( html and html2 ) look the same,so the byte[] method seems to be useless.Now I'm out of ideas...

Comment: We did not even have ideas, since we do not know what input you have, what regex you used, and what exact issue you have.

Comment: The input is a hmtl source,I don't know if I Should post it in here since it's quite big.The thing is,after storing the source code in a String,and than displaying it in textbox,the russian characters look like this ">Đ•Đ¶ĐµĐ´Đ˝ĐµĐ˛Đ˝Ń‹Đµ ĐşĐľĐĽĐ¸ĐşŃŃ".That's my problem.I need it to recognize russian characters.

Comment: Try `var decoded = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetBytes(input_str.ToCharArray()); var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);`

Comment: Now it looks something like this: Ежед�?е�?�?N�е �s�l�Lи�sN�N� ""

Comment: FIXED IT:I had to specify the encoding for the WebClient web = new WebClient(); This is how I fixed everything: web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by specifying the Encoding in the WebClient

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```